# Is local oscillator light polarised?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-optics

If a laser is used as a local oscillator in the homodyne setup does this mean the light it produces is polarised? (I am looking at this from the context of quantum physics and random number generators, if that changes anything?)

Comment: I think the idea of mixing (homo- heterodyne) doesn't have much to do with polarization.

Comment: From a practical point of view, laser light is almost always polarized in one direction. Therefore it also is for local oscillators. But I don't know, if it would make a difference, if it wasn't.

Comment: @Joseph The laser in that paper is polarized (specs for the specific laser http://www.sumielectric.com/otc_pdfs/Devices/DWDM_Laser_Diodes/Cooled_Laser_Diodes_for_DWDM/SLT5411_5413%28revJ%29.pdf). Its polarization (via the HWP) is circular to guarantee that the PBS splits the beam 50/50

Comment: @Punk_Physicist Is the laser producing linearly polarised light or circular? Either way the HWP will just rotate it by a given angle so I still can't see the point in it.

Comment: @Joseph The spec sheet doesn't say but I believe it should be linear (as I believe this is a typical feature of DFB diode lasers AFAIR).

Comment: @Punk_Physicist So in your last comment why did you say its polarisation is circular? I don't think the HWP changes light from linear to circular polarisation?

Comment: @Joseph You are correct (I was thinking quarter wave plate). The HWP acts as a convenient way to rotate the linear polarization angle (to make it diagonal with respect to the PBS).

Answer (score 0):

Laser light is *typically* polarized, though there can be exceptions where there isn't quite enough coherence and the light comes out as unpolarized.

However, the fact that you're using a given laser source as a local oscillator in a homodyne setup essentially means that you trust it to be one of the most stable, coherent sources in your experiment. As such, that carries an implicit guarantee that the light is fully polarized (and that its polarization fully matches the modes that you want to analyze). If it wasn't polarized, it wouldn't be coherent enough for that application, and you wouldn't be using it for it.